# Code Stopping when Opening an Oledbconnection

Tags: vb.net, database-connection, connection-string, oledb

Running the following code, my program just will not get past the 'connection.Open()' line in this sub. I had a similar problem before where I was using a datareader when it was not needed, but in this sub I am not doing anything like that, merely opening a connection to the database. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong here, especially as there are no errors or anything.

```
Using connection As New OleDbConnection(connectionstring)
    connection.Open()

    Dim Command As New OleDbCommand("SELECT SUM(Price) FROM ItemsSold", conection)
    Dim Command2 As New OleDbCommand("SELECT SUM(TotalCost) FROM Inventory", connection)
    Dim Turnover As Double = Convert.ToDouble(Command.ExecuteScalar())
    Dim Cost As Double = Convert.ToDouble(Command2.ExecuteScalar())

    lblProfit.Text = "Profit: £" & (Turnover - Cost)

    connection.Close()
End Using
```

Comment: There must be an error - you say it is breaking. Use a Try/Catch to get the results.

Comment: Using a Try/Catch gives me the error "The type initializer for 'System.Transactions.Diagnostics.DiagnosticTrace' threw an exception" Can you enlighten me any on what this means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I replaced the app.config file with a fresh one and the program now works perfectly fine once more. Thanks for your help!